# How to give ability to create custom NID numbers via API REST post when creating content?

Tags: services, 9, nodes

I'm using Drupal 9.4 and I tried to pass in a **nid** value in my POST via the Drupal api. I'm getting the error:

**Response: {"message":"Access denied on creating field \u0027nid\u0027."}**

My user has admin rights, but how do I give it access to create a custom nid?